# how to start a new activity in one page on clicking a button in other page

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created an remote controller app in android. In the main page,there are few keys which on pressing sends a signal from the mobile. First of all it asks for a configuration file and parse the file and save the control options in a spinbox. When a particular key is pressed he corresponding control from the spinbox is selected and the signal is sent. 
In next screen i would like to have only the keys which on pressed should select the control in the main screen and it should send the signal. In short i should be able to access all the elements in my main_screen.java.

Comment: So your full program is in Java?

Comment: Questions should be presented with more detail , preferably some code, that shows that "I did XYZ and it failed, this is my error" or "here's where I am after I tried XYZ " ,etc. As much as we'd like to help, we won't really even be able to starting from general situation

Answer (score 1):

In this you can access your keys in second screen by sending keys from first screen by click on button through this code

```
Intent in=new Intent(this,yournextActivity.class)
```

e.g:- my current class is hello.java and next class is Applet.java then through intent

```
Intent in=new Intent(hello.this,Applet.class)
```

to pass data to next class use this...

```
in.putExtras(key,value);
```

e.g:- my value is `String s="Welcome"` then i can pass this s to next class like this

```
in.putExtras("Yours",s);
```

key should be any text.....

on second class receive this String through this code

```
Intent in=getIntent();
String m=in.getStringExtras("Yours");
```

where m is receiving string and "Yours" is the key that you pass from first class...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass data from one activity to another, you can do that with the help of **intent**

to pass data use `putExtras()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourSecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "Value");
startActivity(intent);
```

and to receive it in second activity use:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

**Note** i am explaining above as assuming that i am passing data of string type ! so while receiving data, it depends on type of data you are receiving get that accordingly like i used `geString("key");`

Answer (score 0):

you could pass things by using intents, but have you considered using fragments instead of multiple activities ?

it could even be better if you actually wish the app to work on large screens.